# How do I remove invisible files / folders from my Time Machine backup?

Tags: macos, time-machine

I use the methods [here](https://superuser.com/questions/111363/how-do-i-trim-my-time-machine-backups-and-find-and-exclude-frequently-updated-lar) to trim files from my backup and exclude them from future backups. I have `~/.dropbox` excluded, but I don't know how to delete all current backups because it's invisible (and doesn't show up when I Enter Time Machine). What's the trick to ditch invisible files' backups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! found a way. You can view an invisible directory in the Finder by using **Go -> Go to Folder...** (command-shift-G) and enter the path. Once it's showing, Enter Time Machine and follow the steps [here](https://superuser.com/questions/111363/how-do-i-trim-my-time-machine-backups-and-find-and-exclude-frequently-updated-lar). Note: you can delete the folder you're looking at (instead of a file/folder within it) by righ/control-clicking in the Finder window in Time Machine and selecting the Delete All... option with its name there.

I'm not sure how you'd remove an invisible FILE instead of a folder though...

Answer (score 1):

Related to your question: to remove files or folders that are not even accessible to an administrative account<sup>†</sup> you'd have to [invoke "Enter Time Machine" as root](https://superuser.com/questions/35152/how-do-i-retrieve-files-from-time-machine-backups-from-another-computer/35309#35309).

<sup>†</sup> Like MySQL log files, owned by `_mysql` in group `wheel`